# How to keep track of changes within an object?

Tags: angularjs

I have a ui-grid whose data is an array of objects, for simplicity we'll call this `array1`. Each object within `array1` has another array of objects, `array2`. One of the columns of the ui-grid is the length of `array2`.

**How can I keep that column up to date with a live count?**

Here's what I have now:

```
$scope.array1 = [
    {id:0,array2:[{id:0,name:"foo"},{id:1,name:"bar"}], 
        count: $scope.array1[0].array2.length},
    {id:1,array2:[{id:0,name:"thing"}], 
        count: $scope.array1[1].array2.length},
]

$scope.uigrid.data = array1;
```

However, if I add new objects to an `array2` array, `array1.count` does not update in the uigrid, unless I alter the actual value like this:

```
$scope.addToArray2(array1,name){
    // logic to add another object to array2
    $scope.array1.count += 1;
}
```

Is there a way around this?

[In order to illustrate this further, I made simplified version plunker, in which a member of an object keeps track of the count of objects.](https://plnkr.co/edit/k2UDGz08Em8HwKpid3Rd?p=preview) Press "Add OK" then "Add OKCount" then add a few more OKs, followed by another "Add OKCount". You will see that the value in the object is frozen, and not connected to the live data.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but your plunker works for me.

Comment: this isn't a sane way to do this.  besides the fact that your `addToArray2` function isn't altering the value you think it is, tracking the count of an array in another variable is unnecessary and error prone.  Your plunker doesn't even have a ui-grid, which is what you need a solution for.

Comment: @ChrisStanley The issue with the plunker is the OKCounts don't update as more counts are added.

Comment: @Claies The issue is more about if/how I can have an object member that is updated with live data, I only mentioned ui-grid because I assumed it had some sort of functionality built in for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Define your array without the count explicitly defined:

```
$scope.array1 = [
{id:0,array2:[{id:0,name:"foo"},{id:1,name:"bar"}], 
{id:1,array2:[{id:0,name:"thing"}],
....
]
```

Then use the `.gridOptions` declaration style within ui-grid:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
};

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
  {name: 'id'},
  {name: 'array2'},
  {name: 'count', field: 'array2.length'}
]

$scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.array1;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

Further examples of complex bindings can be found in the official documentation at http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/106_binding.

Comment: So then, is it not possible to have object members hold live data?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you are trying to figure out here.  Yes, definitely, you can hold live data in an object.  In particular, you were asking about a piece of data which is already provided by another mechanism, and asking why it wasn't in sync.  my contention is that you should never store the same value in two different places and then try to sync the two values.  also, why say "I ***have*** a ui-grid" in the question, and then say you don't in the comments?